# JavaScript For Loop double value 365 times

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I am struggling to make a For Loop statement in JavaScript that will double .01 365 times (double a penny for a year).   Please help!

This doubles the penny but only up to the amount of 365...how do i get it to double 365 times?

```
var i = .01
for (; i < 365; i *=2){
    console.log(i);
}
```

Thank you for your help!!

Comment: you need two variables, one to count from 1 to 365, and one to store a dollar amount

Comment: Is this what you want to console? 

0.01, 0.02, 0.04, 0.08, 0.06.....etc

Comment: `0.01 * Math.pow(2, 365)` ?

Comment: yes, I want the console to show .01, .02, .04, etc  365 times ...how do i set it up with 2 variables?

Comment: `(double a penny for a year).`  Eh??,  Solutions so far are doubling a penny every day for a year.  Is that what your after..  Are you setting up a bank for savings investments, you can have some of my money at that rate.. :)

Comment: hahahaha.....no bank, just homework ;)      seems easy enough but we haven't even learned loops yet :/

Answer (score 9):

If you know precisely how many times you need to double the number (365 in this case), then you really don't even need a for loop. You can just multiple by a power of two:

```
let i = 0.01 * Math.pow(2, 365);
```

Comment: thank you....this is part of a beginning JavaScript class however and we are supposed to use a loop.  The difficult part is we have not even gone over loops yet!

Answer (score 2):

Simple, you are using the same value for counting and multiplying. If you want to finish it off with 1 variable, then you have to put the value you expect to get at the end of 365 loops on the underscored part: `for (var i = 0.01; i <= __; i++) {`. But, an easier way to do this is:

```
var penny = 0.01;
for (var i = 0; i < 365; i++) {
  console.log(penny);
  penny = penny*2;
}
console.log(penny);
```